# Android CameraX and Google ML Kit - QR-Code Scanner, onSuccess and onFailure never called

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-mlkit

This code just shows minimal requirement to use the QR-Code functionality of ML Kit.
When executing the ML task, the task only calls onComplete and then onCanceled. Am I missing something?

The app first asks for camera permission, then after granting the permission the CameraX PreviewView is displayed. Pointing the camera now to a QR-Code or not, never leads to a onSuccess or onFailure call. The app uses an experimental API for permissions in jetpack compose with:
"com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.24.12-rc".

I want to use this in my Kotlin-Multiplatform project and it was not working there, so I created a toy project in Android Studio to see if the isolated example is working.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Size
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.ExperimentalPermissionsApi
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.PermissionStatus
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.rememberPermissionState
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.shouldShowRationale
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScannerOptions
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.common.Barcode
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import com.wolf.sendanything.ui.theme.SendAnythingTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.util.concurrent.Executor
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

@androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      SendAnythingTheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
          App()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
@Composable
fun App() {
  val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
  var qrCodeData by remember { mutableStateOf("Nothing scanned yet") }

  if (cameraPermissionState.status == PermissionStatus.Granted) {
    Box {
      CameraPreviewView(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)) { qrCodeData = it }
      Text(
        text = qrCodeData,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        color =  Color.White,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
          .background(Color.Black)
          .padding(15.dp),
      )
    }
  } else {
    CameraPermissions()
  }
}


@androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
@Composable
fun CameraPreviewView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, updateLabel: (String) -> Unit) {
  val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
  val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

  AndroidView(
    modifier = modifier,
    factory = { context ->
      val previewView = PreviewView(context).apply {
        scaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
      }

      val previewUseCase = Preview.Builder().build()
      previewUseCase.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

      coroutineScope.launch {
        val cameraProvider = context.getCameraProvider()
        val analysisUseCase = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
          .setTargetResolution(Size(1920, 1080))
          .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
          .build()

        analysisUseCase.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { imageProxy ->
          imageAnalysis(imageProxy, updateLabel)
        }

        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
          lifecycleOwner,
          CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
          previewUseCase,
          analysisUseCase
        )
      }

      previewView
    }
  )
}

@androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage
fun imageAnalysis(imageProxy: ImageProxy, updateLabel: (String) -> Unit) {
  Log.d("QRCodeManager", "Received Image Proxy")

  val imageData = imageProxy.image ?: return
  val qrCodeScannerOptions = BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
    .build()
  BarcodeScanning.getClient(qrCodeScannerOptions).use { scannerClient ->
    val inputImage =
      InputImage.fromMediaImage(imageData, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

    Log.d("QRCodeManager", "Image Analysis started")
    scannerClient.process(inputImage)
      .addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d("QRCodeManager", "QR-Success")
        val qrData = it.firstOrNull()?.rawValue ?: return@addOnSuccessListener
        updateLabel(qrData)
      }
      .addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d("QRCodeManager", "QR-Failed")
        updateLabel("Error scanning")
      }
      .addOnCompleteListener {
        Log.d("QRCodeManager", "QR-Completed")
        imageProxy.close()
      }
      .addOnCanceledListener {
        Log.d("QRCodeManager", "QR-Canceled")
      }
  }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun CameraPermissions() {
  val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

  Column {
    if (cameraPermissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) {
      Text("The Camera permission is needed for QR-Code Scanning")
    }
    Button(onClick = { cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }) {
      Text("Give Camera Permission")
    }
  }
}

private suspend fun Context.getCameraProvider(): ProcessCameraProvider =
  suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this).also { future ->
      future.addListener({
        continuation.resume(future.get())
      }, executor)
    }
  }

private val Context.executor: Executor
  get() = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
```

Project Gradle File:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module Gradle File:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.qrcode"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-video:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.2")
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.24.12-rc")

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha13'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

Manifest only added Camera permission, else default:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: Is there any error logs related to ML Kit you can share?